# PHP loop gives the same results for every item in the loop

Tags: php, loops

I have a loop in a custom CMS that creates a drop down and allows me to select and change the author of of a post.

Unfortunately it doesn't work and every single option have the syntax 'selected' when it should just be one of them.

What have I done?

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rows)) {
printf ('<option value=%d',$auth_id);

if ($auth_id == $current_auth) {
    echo ' selected';

}

printf (">%s", $name);
}
```

Comment: Where do you set the values `$auth_id` and `$current_auth`?

Answer (score 1):

`$auth_id` isn't changing anywhere. Your script could look like this

```
$auth_id = 0;
$current_auth = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rows)) {
  $auth_id++; // ?? change here
  printf ('<option value=%d',$auth_id);

  if ($auth_id == $current_auth) {
      echo ' selected';

  }

  printf (">%s", $row['name']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace $auth_id and $name with the data from the row, e.g. $row['auth_id'] or whatever your fields are named.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not using $row at all in that code, is that correct? Naturally $auth_id and $current_auth will not change.